# How to make rerouting using skobbler iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, routes, skmaps

I'm having a problem with rerouting feature in skobbler iOS SDK i can found the following code into the documentation but i cannot find it in SDK that i downloaded from Cocoapods!!!

```
- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didUpdateRouteTraffic:(SKRouteTrafficUpdate *)trafficUpdate {
    NSLog(@"Traffic changed on the current route.");    
    //Rerouting can be done after the traffic changed
    [[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]rerouteWithTrafficInfo];
}
```

I got the SDK from Cocoapods using this data
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools'

I don't know what is wrong is it the SDK version if yes which version should i use? else what should i do to make rerouting when user takes another route?

Answer (score 1):

The Scout traffic feature is not available for CocoaPods